# Implementing "dependant: :orphan"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, `Exam` belongs_to `Questions`, in that the exam model has a column called "Current question".

exam.rb:

```
belongs_to :current_question, class_name: "Question", foreign_key: "question_id"
```

When I delete a `question`, I want any `exams` with a current_question set as the deleted question to have current_question set to nil.

Currently, if I delete a question I get this:

```
'PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "questions" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_8b5180f7e7" on table "exams" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "exams". : DELETE FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = $1'
```

I'm planning on doing this: a 'before_destroy' callback on the Question class, that gets all of the exams associated with the question & sets the current_question to nil.

Is this the simplest implementation?

Comment: Do you have an inverse association on the question? You could add `dependent: :nullify` to it